# Tkinter window does not update correctly when running

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Tkinter window show updated data but it only pops up after 13 seconds with just the last value. I want it to pop up and change the values on screen. Mind you, the big goal of this code is to take data from a database (which updates every 3 seconds) and show the data onscreen, while running continuously, so if the answer could include some pointers on the "after" or "update" functions it would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have so far.

```
from tkinter import *
import time


class GUI(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        Tk.wm_title(self, "Main Window")
        self.container = Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)

        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        self.frame = StartPage(self.container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = self.frame
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, controller):
        frame = self.frames[controller]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = Label(self, text="Current ID:\n")
        self.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.data_label = Label(self)
        self.data_label.pack()
        self.update_data()

    def update_data(self):
        var1 = StringVar()
        for i in range(10):
            var1.set(str(i))
            self.data_label.config(text=str(i))
            time.sleep(1)


main = GUI()
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: *so if the answer could include some pointers on the "after" or "update" functions it would be greatly appreciated* - You seem to know exactly what you need. Have you tried using these functions?

Comment: Yes, i tried them but unsuccessfully.

Comment: You're telling it to sleep, so that's what it's doing. There are many, many, many questions on this site related to using `sleep` with tkinter.

Comment: The reason i told it to sleep was to see the values change in the tkinter window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a partial answer. The reason you don't see any updates is that `time.sleep()` suspends the process and does not allow for tkinter to repaint the window.

You don't use the label textvariable correctly. Specify it in the label and the label will change as you change the textvariable.

You use both pack and grid at the same time which may cause problems.

I have not used `after()` in a class before so I don't know how to work it, but this example should give you some pointers. I'm keeping console printouts in the code so I can see what it does.

```
from tkinter import *
import time


class GUI(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        Tk.wm_title(self, "Main Window")
        self.container = Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)

        self.frames = {}
        self.frame = StartPage(self.container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = self.frame
        self.frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, controller):
        frame = self.frames[controller]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.update_data()
        print('Done')


class StartPage(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.label = Label(self, text="Current ID:\n")
        self.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.var1 = StringVar()
        self.data_label = Label(self, textvariable=self.var1)
        self.data_label.pack()
        self.update_idletasks() # Calls all pending idle tasks

    def update_data(self):
        if not self.var1.get(): self.var1.set('0')

        iteration = int(self.var1.get())
        print('iteration', iteration)

        if iteration < 3:
            iteration = iteration + 1
            self.var1.set(str(iteration))
            self.update_idletasks() # Calls all pending idle tasks
            time.sleep(1)
            self.update_data()


main = GUI()
main.mainloop()
```

You will have to research `after()` yourself as I can't help you there.

Comment: Thank you! It shows the value onscreen changing as it should!

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but the data i want to show in the GUI is sent to the update_data method using a tuple. How could i make it show the elements in the tuple, one by one?

Comment: Tuples uses indexes, just like lists. Index starts at 0. So, for getting the second value in the tuple `t = (1, 2, 3, 4)` you can write it as `t[1]`.

Comment: The use of `pack` and `grid` in the original code is perfectly fine, since the two are used on widgets with different parents.